# How do i change a for loop to a do while loop

Tags: c

how do i convert the for loop in the below code to a do while loop,

```
for (int i= 0; i< N_list;i++ ){
        k=0;
        fscanf(fp_in, "%d %d %d", &fixation_number, &x, &y);
    while (!((x == -1) && (y ==-1))){
            Point[k].x = x;
            Point[k].y =y;
            Point[k].id_number =k+1;
```

Comment: You are missing some braces. And the indenting is inconsistent.

Comment: What is the relevance of the code after the first line for this question?

Comment: Fix your code with all the proper braces, indent it in a logical manner, and show your attempts at making a do-while-loop.

Comment: A `do` loop executes its body unconditionally at least once, whereas a `for` loop doesn't. `for` loops are usually not good candidates for conversion to `do` loops. It has to be obvious that there is always at least one iteration. A for loop with a blank top like `for (;;)` which has a termination test at the bottom of the block is an example of a good candidate for a `do` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task sounds a bit like a homework problem, so I won't give you working code outright but I will help you out a bit:

A `for` loop `for(init; cond; increment) { loop-body; }` is equivalent to:

```
init;
while(cond)
{
    loop-body;
    increment;
}
```

Now, a `do-while` loop is similar to a while loop, except that even if `cond` is false from the start, `loop-body` will be executed at least once.  In other words, the above `while` loop is equivalent to the following `do-while` loop:

```
init;
int first_run = 1;
do
{ 
    if(first_run)
    {
        if((cond) == 0) break;
        first_run = 0;
    }
    loop-body;
    increment;
}
while(cond);
```

Comment: One could do without the extra variable and conditions: `{ init; do { if (!condition) break; loop-body; increment; } while(true); }`

Comment: @Swordfish I agree, but I feel that for a beginner at C the extra logic may help them follow the path of the conversion from `for` to `do-while`